# "A remote operation is taking longer than expected" x64

Tags: visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

First off, I think I've been to every website and forum there is that's discussing this issue and I've tried many different things. I'm at my wits end. This is the dumbest thing and I just want to start coding again!

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop. I have a x64 project I'm trying to run in Debug mode using the local windows debugger. The only external library I'm using is that of which is required to run DX11.

I attempt to run my program and it freezes. A window pops up saying "A remote operation is taking longer than expected."

I click Terminate and another window pops up asking if I'd like to terminate the remote session. Why yes, I would.

Then it says, "Unable to start program (my path leading to my .exe). The network connection to the Visual Studio Remote Debugger has been closed."

To my understanding, because Visual Studio itself is a 32 bit application, it needs to use the Remote Debugger to compile to x64. Is that correct?

Regardless, I'm still failing to see where that would break down. I've ran several repairs on VS and upgraded to Service Pack 2 (or 1, whichever is the latest).

I've ran a windows repair and uninstalled any VMWare type stuff on my computer. I'm not using a VPN.

I've even copied msvsmon.exe from my laptop (working instance of the project) over to this computer and still no luck.

I'm about ready to Nuke my OS and do a clean install on everything. *sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. It wasn't Windows Firewall like other threads describe. It was my internet filter. I guess it decided to try and block msvsmon.exe because it was using the network. Adding it, along with WDExpress.exe to the application exceptions list did the trick.

Comment: i was trying to fix it with firewall and your answer reminded me that i have installed an internet filter app for testing which was causing this issue.

Comment: In my case it wasn't any firewall setting at all. I managed to solve the problem just by running msvsmon.exe from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64. It seems like, each time when I debug the program from VS, it tries to start msvsmon (the remote debugger), but due to some networking issues it fails. When I explicitly run it, it keeps running in the background (even minimized in the tray) and VS connects to it correctly without any issues. I haven't hit the titular error even once after this solution. (Windows 10, VS 15 Community)

Comment: How did you determine that there was a problem starting msvsmon? I have run it manually but am still stuck at the 'operation taking longer than expected' dialog. Msvsmon just states that a new server has been started and is waiting for new connections...